# Use Range().Find().Row result in If Not condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find the row where "1" is first mentionned in the A column.

```
Dim begin1, end1 As Integer
begin1 = 0
end1 = 0


begin1 = Range("A:A").Find("1", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
end1 = Range("A:A").Find("1", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row

If Not begin1 Is Nothing Then
```

At the moment this "If Not" condition doesn't work because it is the wrong object. I don't know enough VBA to know how I can change this condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: How about `If begin1 <> 0 Then...` ?

Comment: It did something, I know get an error 91 Object variable not set in regards to the begin1 = ... and end1 = ...

Comment: `If Not begin1 Is Nothing Then` is a check you'd typically use for an object. `begin1` is an integer that will either be 0 or a row number. Also this check is obsolete, since `begin1 = Range("A:A").Find("1", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues).Row` will throw an error if "1" is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, be careful of how you use comma's in the declaration.

```
Dim begin1, end1 As Integer
```

This results in begin1 being declared as 'variant' and end1 as integer.
If you want to use commas then the following will declare both as integers:

```
Dim begin1 as integer, end1 as integer
```

Then if you want to use an integer in an if...then statement you should use:

```
If begin1 <> 0 then
```

If you want to use a range it would be:

```
if Not begin1 is nothing then
```

Comment: Will still throw errors if nothing is found (Object not set on the `.Row` method of the found range) - This means the `If begin1 <> 0 Then` line is obsolete in the first place. Other than that you're totally right of course.

Comment: You are right, but errorhandling wasn't addressed in the question so I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Declare begin1 and end1 as ranges, then check if they are found (you only need to check the former as end1 will be found even if there is only one 1 in the whole column) and if they are use the row property of the found cell.

```
Sub x()

Dim begin1 As Range, end1 As Range

With Range("A:A")
    Set begin1 = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set end1 = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(1), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With

If Not begin1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "First row is " & begin1.Row
    MsgBox "Last row is " & end1.Row
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If I do that the program does indeed compile but I was using begin1 and end1 as integers later on : For i = begin1 To end1 - X + 1. That doesn't work if begin1 and end1 are ranges right ?

Comment: No, but you could declare two other variables as Long and set them each to the row of the two found cells. Personally, I would just use `begin1.row`, but if you are repeatedly using it, a variable might make sense. (Or change the names of the range variables.)

Comment: As @SJR said, I'd stick with `begin1.row`.  You could use an `Integer` variable - in the `If...End If` block add `iBegin=begin1.row` remembering to declare it as an integer first... then add your first 1 into row 32768 and you'll get an `overflow` error.  If you really need it just as a number use a `Long` instead.